# Convert List of Lists with maps in List

Tags: flutter, dart

What is the best way to convert this:

```
[[{name:"John", uid: 1}], [{name:"Mary, uid: 2}]]
```

To:

```
[[1], [2]]
```

Comment: result is array of uid?

Comment: list of lists of uids

Comment: What did you try, where are you stuck? Can you post some code?

Comment: I want to know the best way ... I can loop through the List and add the uids to another list, but I'm sure there is a better and faster way. In case the List has a lot of entries.

Comment: Well, the first step would be to make it compile at all. That's why I was asking for code. Your single line there does not compile, so I have no idea what you even *want*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end it's loops, the question is just how many of them you see and how many have been hiden away by other methods so your code is more readable.

```
void main() {
  final data = [[{"name":"John", "uid": 1}], [{"name":"Mary", "uid": 2}]];
  
  final uids = data.map((x) => x.map((y) => y["uid"]).toList()).toList();
  
  print("Type: ${uids.runtimeType}");
  print("Value: ${uids}");
}
```

Will print (for example in dartpad):

> Type: JSArray<List<Object?>>
>
> Value: [[1], [2]]

Comment: I was looking for a list of ids ... I don't know how to convert ((1),(2)) to a list.

Comment: You convert it by adding `toList()`, I spelled it out.

Comment: Two toLists ... I tried just one. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just map the list, followed by mapping the inner list(s).

```
  var list = [
    [
      {"name": "John", "uid": 1}
    ],
    [
      {"name": "Mary", "uid": 2}
    ]
  ];

  var ids = list.map((item) => item.map((i) => i["uid"]).toList()).toList();

  // ids === [[1], [2]]
```